# css path for error 404

Tags: html, css, http-status-code-404

I've made a error 404 page with css in the same folder basicly both the html and the css are in the same folder named "error".
Now, my htacces contains the following :

ErrorDocument 404 /error/error_404.php

it works great if in my url there's /error/randomtext
but when a wrong page happens somewhere else than the error folder, it doesn't charge the css, what do I do ?

css include :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../error/style.css">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the path of the CSS file to be absolute rather than relative :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/error/style.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an absolute path to reference the css, like `href="/error/style.css"`.
(`..` moves up one level in the document tree, and is therefore always relative.)